# ¿Cómo habilitar la tecla "Enter" en un formulario de Login en Java Swing?

Tags: java, java-swing, teclado

Tengo mi Formulario de Logeo, me gustaría poder usar la tecla "enter", ya que actualmente necesita hacer click con el mouse.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: En el campo `Box_contra` para obtener la contraseña, en vez de `getText(); `podrías utilizar el siguiente código: `String pass = new String(Box_contra.getPassword());`

Answer (score 0):

la solución mas rápida y sencilla seria añadir un keylistener al JTextField que contiene la contraseña puesto que va a ser el ultimo campo donde se va a introducir información antes de iniciar sesión y por tanto va a ser el que vaya a tener el foco de atención por parte de la ventana debido a que si lo añades al boton, solo funcionara el enter cuando el botón este seleccionado y no cuando acabes de poner la contraseña con lo cual la solución seria algo así:

```
  campoContraseña.addKeyListener(new KeyListener() {
        @Override
        public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {

        }

        @Override
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
            if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER) {
                iniciarSesion(); //Método que tienes que crearte
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {

        }
    });
```

Dentro del método iniciar sesión introduces todo lo que tienes dentro de ese actionPeformed de tal forma que ese método lo llames tanto desde este keyListener que te acabo de indicar como desde el actionPeformed que acabas de hacer así te evitas duplicar código y queda mejor. Para finalizar y que quede mas "pro" después del mensaje de error yo pondría la siguientes lineas de código:

```
    campoLogin.setText(""); //Vacia el JTextField
    campoPassword.setText("");
    campoLogin.getFocus(); //Esto hace que el cursor se ponga en el campo del login para que el usuario vuelva a iniciar sesión
```

Y ya para finalizar, si quieres puedes cambiar el campo contraseña de JTextField a JPasswordField para que cada vez que añades un carácter aparezca con un asterisco.

Espero haberte ayudado. Un saludo

Comment: Si no se utilizarán los métodos `keyTyped` y `keyReleased` de la clase `KeyListener`, se podría intentar reducir todo ese código utilizando la clase `KeyAdapter` en vez de `KeyListener` y aplicar el `Override` únicamente al método `keyPressed`